# End User Computing Factors that Affect Javascript Loading

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer7

We present video content to end users and I've recently had a user report that they are unable to view the videos (loaded using JW Player 7 self-hosted) in any of the HTML5 supported browsers (IE11 11.9.0060, Chrome 46, Firefox 42).

We have tested in these browsers repeatedly before going live and we were never able to re-create the issues reported by this end user

Here is the code that is used to instantiate the video player:

```js
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/jwplayer_license.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/player.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div id="visualSPPlayer">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("visualSPPlayer");
playerInstance.setup({
playlist: [{
        image: "http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/screencasts/20002/poster.PNG",
        sources: [ {
            file: "http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/screencasts/20002.mp4"
        }],
         tracks: [{ 
file: "http://sharepoint-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/screencasts/20002/thumbnails.vtt", 
kind: "thumbnails"
}]
    }],
primary: "html5",
width: "100%",
aspectratio: "16:9",
autostart: true,
skin: {
  name: "vapor",
active: "#E16933",
inactive: "#E16933",
background: "#333333"
}
});
</script>
```

This user reports that all they see output in their browser is the: **Loading the player....**

Here is the error the user is reporting in the browser console:

The value of the property 'jwplayer' is null or undefined, Not a function object

My question is what could be contributing to this one user's issue with the videos loading when they load fine for my team and all other users.  What should I have him look into changing?

I've had him test if Javascript is enabled successfully: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled

Comment: There are a million reasons, honestly. One possible reason is that there's some kind of syntax error from something being injected before the content (from a browser extension or even security software). Another likely cause might be another extension interfering or an ad-blocker is not letting him download some dependencies. Ask him to look at his network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools and see if there are any errors downloading any of the external files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have them try another computer in the same office? What about in an incognito window? What about on their phone in the office's wifi? Yeah i suspect the content is possibly being blocked. As @Antiga said, have them look at the network tab to see what other calls are being made, and check to see the http code, they should all be 200.